# How to write shell script,to automate file conversion?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, csh

I have 30 files(ascii),which I want convert to binary.Linux command line(FORTRAN 77 CODE) that has been compiled

```
./rec_binary
```

Relevant part of the code

```
      character*72 ifname,ofname
c
      write(*, fmt="(/'Enter input file name')")
      read(5,85) ifname
85    format(a72)
      write(*, fmt="(/'Enter output file name')")
      read(5,85) ofname
```

Then code asks for input and output file names

```
Enter input file name
rec01.txt

Enter output file name
rec.01
```

How to automate this?I have tried like this

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set list = 'ls rec*.txt'
foreach file ($list)
rec_binary ${file} >
```

Or

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in .txt
do
./rec_binary F
done
```

But I do not have a clue for next step.Text files are

```
rec01.txt
rec02.txt

rec30.txt
```

Output files

```
rec.01
rec.02

rec.30
```

Comment: Does `bash` have `foreach`?

Comment: @sjsam I do not know,what should I put instead for loop?

Comment: `for stuff in $lot` is the usual way. But you should not parse `ls` output as described in [\[ this \]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) link

Comment: Could you update the code with what `rec_binary` is ? I'm sure it's not commonly pre-installed in popular distros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for each in `ls rec*.txt`
do
  op_file=$(echo $each | sed 's/\(rec\)\([0-9]*\).txt/\1\.\2/')
  ./rec_binary <<EOF
$each
$op_file
EOF
done
```

The variable `op_file` converts your rec01.txt to rec.01.

Comment: No.I got this:
ad.sh: command substitution: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
ad.sh: command substitution: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Be careful with the line indentation. Try to follow the indentation as i have used in the script.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had a extra `"` in the script. Please try the latest edited version

Answer (score 1):

Assuming , you have knowledge of rec_binary. I am not sure what it do. I am making this up based on your inputs in question.

```
for i in rec*.txt;
 do
    rec_binary "$i"
done
```

Comment: Not working,when I execute rec_binary,I got question Enter input file name

Comment: This should be the best option provided the the op could suppress the prompt with `rec_binary`

Comment: We need to know more about rec_binary

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of different ways you could do this. One way would to be using a for loop, however, it's unclear if the `rec_binary` command you've shown allows arguments.

```
for i in rec*.txt; do
    num=$( echo $i | egrep -o "\d+" )
    echo ${i} > "rec.${num}"
done
```

If you can do something like this from the command-line `./rec_binary file1 file2`, then that should work. If the `rec_binary` command echos  to stdout then you could send it to a file:

```
for i in rec*.txt; do
    num=$( echo $i | egrep -o "\d+" )
    rec_binary ${i} > "rec.${num}"
done
```

The `$num` variable simply captures the digits from the filename as it loops and then we can use it while running the next command to construct the filename.